# Find Maximum GCD sum without repetition in an array

Tags: java, arrays, python-3.x, algorithm, greatest-common-divisor

I have an array of even number of elements, I have to select n/2( n=array size), pairs and calculate their GCD such that the sum of their GCD is max, given once we use those elements from array, we cannot use them again.

**Example1:** `

> Input : 8 24 12 16
>
> Output : 20

**Explanation**: We select two pairs (8,16) and (12,24) as sum of their GCD is maximum.
If we choose some other pairs, say (8,12) and (24,16), sum of their GCD will be 4+4 =8.

**Example 2:**

> Input : 12 10 36 25 36 16
>
> Output: 45

**Explanation**: We select the following 3 pairs : (36,36), (10,25) and (12,16) as the sum of their GCD is
36+5+4 = 45.

**Our Approach**:

```
for i in range(0,n):
   max = 0;
   for j in range(i+1,n):
      temp = gcd(a[i], a[j]) // standard func to find GCD 
      if(max<temp):
         store i and j
      store max gcd every time and finally make a[i] and a[j] =0 to mark the visited elements
```

**Edited**
**Constraint**: max number of elements = 20, a[i]< 10^9.

Can you suggest an algorithm to optimally satisfy the above testcases in the least time complexity?
Because my approach is failing on multiple testcases.

Comment: Edmonds's algorithm for maximum (non-bipartite) weighted matching will do the trick, but it's hard to believe that a competitive programming site would set constraints to require it. It's possible to approximately encode arbitrary instances in the GCD metric, so unless there's a bound on the maximum number size, I don't think number theory is going to save the day.

Comment: Why is your approach failing?  Wrong answer?  Time limit exceeded?  Something else?  There is no point in finding the wrong answer more quickly.

Comment: *Can you mention the constraints of the problem?* What is the possible array size? What is the size of each array element?

Comment: @rossum On 2, 3, 5, 10, if it's unlucky enough to look for the best match with 2, it will match 2-10, 3-5 for a total of 3 instead of 2-3, 5-10 for a total of 6.

Comment: Our approach is failing due to wrong answer. @rossum

Comment: What does 'without repletion' mean?

Comment: @user207421 Its "repetition" my bad

Answer (score 1):

This is a comment but I am not allowed to post comment yet.
It is not good to solve this problem by looking for the largest gcd.
Take [8,9,24,36], the largest gcd is gcd(24,36) = 12, that will get you gcd(24,36) + gcd(8,9)  = 12+1 =13.
However, the largest sum is given by gcd(8,24) + gcd(9,36) = 8+9 = 17.

Comment: Yes I agree with you. Could you tell any approch or psuedocode to solve the above question.